# Dotfuscator not in VS2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, obfuscation, dotfuscator

I've got VS2008 professional edition installed and can't find Dotfuscator. I also can't find anywhere to download the community edition. It seems that Dotfuscator should already integrated into VS2008, but I only have other tools visible such as Reflector. Is there a way to download Dotfuscator separately?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this [link](http://www.ms-strategies.com/Installing_Visual_Studio.pdf) (it's a PDF), and go to page 9.  You have to choose it when you are installing.  I would say put the disc in again, choose Add/Remove Existing Features, and choose to install it.

Comment: Thanks, I would've thought I'd have selected it but I guess that could be the problem. I put in the VS2008 cd to try and install it and it throws 'A problem was encountered while loading the setup components' error, which seems to be quite a common error on Win7. *sigh*, I'll just leave it and look for some other obfuscator as I my deadline is coming up and so I don't have time to bother reinstalling VS2008 and messing around with compatibility issues. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 2):

If you also have a default installation of Visual Studio 2010 Pro or higher installed you will have the more recent version of Dotfuscator installed (Dotfuscator CE 5).  That version of Dotfuscator will work with any .NET assembly (back to 1.0) with no problems.  In fact, using the newer version of Dotfuscator gives you a better UI as well as a better obfuscation experience (due to the inclusion of SmartObfuscation technology which makes it easier to just "point and shoot").

Comment: Perfect! I had to update some hard-coded paths inside of the project (instead of pointing to where the IDE now knew Dotfuscator was, but whatever).

Answer (score 1):

On my VB2008 Pro installation, I can start Dotfuscator by selecting

> Tools > Dotfuscator Community Edition

.

Comment: That's what I thought, but it's not there. Very strange. I'm running Win7 if that makes a difference? I remember using it on my XP machine, but have been using VS2010 express recently so had never checked if Dotfuscator was present after installation of VS2008 on my Win7 machine.

Comment: @superexsl - Like you, I don't think OS is the issue.  I wonder if Dotfuscator is a VS2008 install option that you didn't select.  You can try rerunning the installer and see if it gives you the option.

Comment: I've tried to rerun the installation from my VS2008 CD but I get the 'problem encountered error" everytime it tries to run setup. It then closes. I've searched around for solutions but most people seem to suggest that I should try uninstalling everything first. Unfortunately, I don't have time for that as my deadline is coming up. VS 2008 is working perfectly, but have a feeling it's the SP1 update that could be causing the CD some compatibility issues.